# Using Contexts that take props with React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom, react-context

I have an application that is tracking information about various servers. I have a web server that I am able to query for the information by server name. I created a context for this information that takes a server name as a prop and updates its data periodically. See below;

ServerContext.js

```
export const ServerDataContext = createContext();

export const ServerDataContextProvider = ({
  children,
  server= "",
}) => {
  const [serverConfig, setServerConfig] = useState({});

  const updateServerData = () => {;
    serverConfigRequest(server).then((res) => {
      setServerConfig((old) => {
        return res;
      });
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("init");
    updateServerData();
    const updateInterval = setInterval(
      updateServerData,
      serverConfigUpdateFrequency * 1000
    );

    return () => {
      clearInterval(updateInterval);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <ServerDataContext.Provider
      value={{
        serverConfig,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </ServerDataContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

In my App.js I use react router to for having a StatusPage for each server. It looks something like this:

App.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="app">
        <Header />
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<div>Overview</div>} />
          <Route
            exact
            path="/server_1"
            element={
              <ServerDataContextProvider server="server_1">
                <StatusPage server="server_1" />
              </ServerDataContextProvider>
            }
          />
          <Route
            exact
            path="/server_2"
            element={
              <ServerDataContextProvider server="server_2">
                <StatusPage server="server_2" />
              </ServerDataContextProvider>
            }
          />
        </Routes>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

I have buttons to go to each page in the header. When I load up the first servers status page the page updates perfectly fine. I see requests on my server coming in at the correct interval for server_1. Then I navigate to server_2 I see the route update in my browser search bar but the content on the page does not. The requests I am receiving on my web server are still for server_1 at the same interval as though i hadnt switched pages. If i refresh the page still at the endpoint for server_2 the content on the page will update properly for server_2 but the same issue occurs with server_1 this time.

Am I using contexts inappropriately? I think the problem is how I have the app structured but am not sure. Any advice is appreciated.

Edit:
https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-haibt-vxm62?file=/src/ServerContext.js

Comment: Something seems a little off in your code snippet. For the route rendering path "/server_2" you appear to be using an entirely different context provider, `ServerDataContextProviderhardwareString` and that doesn't match the closing tag. Is this just a typo or copy/paste error? Think you could create a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces this dual context issue that we could inspect and debug live (*mock the `serverConfigRequest` function OFC*)?

Comment: Hi Drew, that was a copy paste error that I have fixed. I will try to put together a sandbox now.

Comment: I made a code sandbox here (https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-haibt-vxm62?file=/src/ServerContext.js). Let me know if you can access it for some reason. The way it is configured is that server_1 should always be green and server_2 should always be red. You'' find that if you go to server_1 it will be green but when you navigate to 2 it will stay green until you refresh the page. It shows the issue i am running into well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I suspect is happening here is that when the route path switches, the React tree is effectively identical and the context provider for server 2 isn't mounted. *I certainly don't see it mounting at all, even with a mounting `useEffect`, and the server 1 context value is still being provided*.

Adding a React key to each provider in `App` certainly does the trick and informs React that these are actually two different components and that it necessarily needs to remount the provider with the given props and reinstantiate the context value.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<div>Overview</div>} />
  <Route
    path="/server_1"
    element={
      <ServerDataContextProvider key="server_1" server="server_1">
        <StatusPage server="server_1" />
      </ServerDataContextProvider>
    }
  />
  <Route
    path="/server_2"
    element={
      <ServerDataContextProvider key="server_2" server="server_2">
        <StatusPage server="server_2" />
      </ServerDataContextProvider>
    }
  />
</Routes>
```

[image: Edit using-contexts-that-take-props-with-react-router]

[image]
[image]

Alternatively, adding the `server` prop as a dependency in the `ServerDataContextProvider`'s `useEffect` hook will also clear any existing interval timers and restart them with the updated `server` prop's value.

```
useEffect(() => {
  // moved into effect callback to remove as dependency
  const updateServerData = () => {
    setServerConfig((old) => {
      return { server: server == "server_1" ? "G" : "R" };
    });
  };

  console.log("init");
  updateServerData();
  const updateInterval = setInterval(updateServerData, 5 * 1000);

  return () => {
    clearInterval(updateInterval);
  };
}, [server]);
```